# how to save variable value and retrieve it when windows form is closed and reopened in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net windows application I want to store a variable value when form is opened and retrieve this value as soon as form is opened. Please let me know if this can be achieved easily or not.

Comment: how about using a database or text file?

Comment: Use [My.Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/accessing-application-settings)?

Comment: Yeah, resource file o My.settings

Comment: Yes, this can be easily achieved.  Almost as easy as it is to read [ask] and take the [tour].